# How can I check in C# if a Chart's annotations contain an annotation with a specific name using Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

The Annotations object in Chart in C# is derived from a Collection<>, but I cannot use .Any() or .Find() methods on it for some reason.

So this does not work:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

Chart chart = new Chart();

// Your annotation name to search for
string annotationNameToFind = "YourAnnotationName";

// Check if the annotation exists with the given name
bool annotationExists = chart.Annotations.Any(annotation => annotation.Name == annotationNameToFind);
```

It has a method .Contains(), but I cannot use Linq with it.

How do I check if the annotations in a chart contain a specific annotation by name with Linq or something similar without using a for or foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotationcollection?view=netframework-4.8.1) there is [FindByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotationcollection.findbyname?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-windows-forms-datavisualization-charting-annotationcollection-findbyname(system-string)) Method.

> Returns An Annotation object, or null if the object does not exist

```cs
var annotaion = chart.Annotations.FindByName(annotationNameToFind);
bool annotationExists = annotaion is not null;
```

Also, you can iterate over them With LINQ

```cs
bool annotationExists = chart.Annotations.GetEnumerator().Any(annotation => annotation.Name == annotationNameToFind);
```

Comment: Items is inaccessible in annotation due to protection level.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not exam it. I just copy and paste from documentation without Notice that it's Protected property, `GetEnumerator()` should be fine it's publicly accessible Method